# How to get the current filename in Hadoop Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using the [WordCount](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.18.2/mapred_tutorial.html) example and in the Reduce function, I need to get the file name.

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
      sum += values.next().get();
    }
    String filename = ((FileSplit)(.getContext()).getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();
    // ----------------------------^ I need to get the context and filename!
    key.set(key.toString() + " (" + filename + ")");
    output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
  }
}
```

This is the above modified code currently, where I wanna get the filename to be printed for the word. I tried following [Java Hadoop: How can I create mappers that take as input files and give an output which is the number of lines in each file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367389/java-hadoop-how-can-i-create-mappers-that-take-as-input-files-and-give-an-outpu) but I couldn't get the `context` object.

I am new to hadoop and need this help. Any help guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get `context`, because `context` is a construct of the "new API", and you are using the "old API".

Check out this word count example instead: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount

See the signature of the reduce function in this case:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
```

See! The context! Notice in this example it imports from `.mapreduce.` instead of `.mapred.`.

This is a common issue for new hadoop users, so don't feel bad. In general you want to stick to the new API for a number of reasons. But, be very careful of examples that you find. Also, realize that the new API and old API are not interoperable (e.g., you can't have a new API mapper and an old API reducer).

Comment: just curious - what is the reason for preferring the new api instead of the old api - i thought both of them would be supported - maybe I am not up to date.

Comment: How to get the filename in the reduce function of the old API?

Answer (score 4):

Using the old MR API (org.apache.hadoop.mapred package), add the below to the mapper/reducer class.

```
String fileName = new String();
public void configure(JobConf job)
{
    filename = job.get("map.input.file");
}
```

Using the new MR API (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce package), add the below to the mapper/reducer class.

```
String fileName = new String();
protected void setup(Context context) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException
{
    fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used this way and it works!!!

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
  private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
  private Text word = new Text();

  public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      FileSplit fileSplit = (FileSplit)reporter.getInputSplit();
      String filename = fileSplit.getPath().getName();
      word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
      output.collect(word, one);
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if I can improve it!